# How to format a Fraction as string in Python?

Tags: python

I'm experimenting with [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) and I'm wondering how to convert them into decimal strings, possibly specifying the precision. Say we have:

```py
from fractions import Fraction

a = Fraction.from_float(1e10)
b = Fraction.from_float(1e-10)
c = a + b
```

`str(c)` returns a string based on the numerator/denominator of the fraction, i.e. `773712524553362671819689765245533627/77371252455336267181195264`.

`f"{c:.20f}"` errors with `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Fraction.__format__`.

Converting back to float via `float(c)` allows to obtain a string, but of course loses the precision again.

What I'm interested is to represent `c` as a string like `"1000000000.0000000001[...]"`. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: note, one problem that isn't directly related to your question, but  `b = Fraction.from_float(1e-10)` is going to give you something imprecise. You should use `Fraction('1e-10')`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that's what I was expecting. I basically wanted to get a feeling of the imprecision by printing it with many digits.

Comment: Yea, you can toggle the precision with decimal as well, see the function I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do is just piggy-back on top of `decimal.Decimal`, so:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal

a = Fraction.from_float(1e10)
b = Fraction.from_float(1e-10)
c = a + b
print(f"{Decimal(c.numerator) / Decimal(c.denominator):10.10f}")
```

Actually, I would use:

```
def fraction_to_decimal_string(fraction, precision=16):
    with decimal.localcontext() as context:
        context.prec = precision
        decimal_string = str(decimal.Decimal(c.numerator) / decimal.Decimal(c.denominator))
    return decimal_string
```

Then you can check:

```
print(fraction_to_decimal_string(c, 21))
print(fraction_to_decimal_string(c, 30))
print(fraction_to_decimal_string(c, 50))
```

For example, the above gives me:

```
10000000000.0000000001
10000000000.0000000001000000000
10000000000.000000000100000000000000003643219731550
```